# How to represent a Linux path while running in a Windows machine?

Tags: java, path

I am developing a Java program that will run on Windows machines but will allow users to send commands to Linux servers. Some of these commands allow the user to specify a Linux-compliant path, e.g. "/folder/file.txt".

Usually, I would use [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) to validate and represent the paths entered by users. However, since the program is running on Windows, the JVM will instead default to representing Windows paths, e.g. "C:\folder\file.txt".

Other than performing string manipulations, how can I represent a Linux-type path in Java while running in a Windows machine? Is there a way to "force" the `Path` class to pretend it is on Linux?

Comment: I would ignore the `PATH` variable entirely and just use a configuration file that is shipped with the app.  Specify the server side paths to be used in that configuration file.

Comment: @markspace this is not about the PATH variable at all. My problem is about accepting and validating user inputs that represent Linux paths while the JVM runs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To represent `win` path in `unix` format, you could do something like this:

```
String unix = StreamSupport.stream(Paths.get(win).spliterator(), false)
                  .map(Object::toString)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining("/", "/", ""));
```

This will convert `C:\\folder\\file.txt` into `/folder/file.txt` but it's a bit of a hack.